# Multiple command output into variable Bash script with $()

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I reviewed the multiple threads on this and am still having issues, here is the command I'm trying to execute.  Commands without the `$()` print the desired output to the console without issue, I just can't seem to put that value into a variable to be used later on.

```
MODEL3= $(/usr/sbin/getSystemId | grep "Product Name" | awk '{print $4}')
```

but

```
MODEL3= /usr/sbin/getSystemId | grep "Product Name" | awk '{print $4}'
```

-will output to the console.
Thanks so much!

Comment: the problem is the space after `MODEL3=`. this shouldn't be.

Comment: Grep is not needed. `MODEL3=$(/usr/sbin/getSystemId | awk '/Product Name/ {print $4}')`

Answer (score 5):

That is correct:

```
MODEL3=$(/usr/sbin/getSystemId | grep "Product Name" | awk '{print $4}')
```

But you can write the same without `grep`:

```
MODEL3=$(/usr/sbin/getSystemId | awk '/Product Name/{print $4}')
```

Now you have the result in the `MODEL3` variable and you can use it further as `$MODEL3`:

```
echo "$MODEL3"
```

Comment: thank you! I simply retyped my echo statement on a new line of vi and it worked as it should.

Comment: You should use `echo "$MODEL3"` with double quotes. The situations where unquoted variable interpolations are strictly correct are rare, although too many people are getting away with it too often to really understand the magnitude of the problem.

Comment: @triplee: Thank you for the tip, fixed!

Answer (score 3):

#### Spaces Not Legal in Variable Assignments

Variable assignments must not have spaces between the variable name, the assignment operator, and the value. Your current line says:

```
MODEL3= $(/usr/sbin/getSystemId | grep "Product Name" | awk '{print $4}')
```

This actually means "run the following expression with an empty environment variable, where MODEL3 is set but empty."

What you *want* is an actual assignment:

```
MODEL3=$(/usr/sbin/getSystemId | grep "Product Name" | awk '{print $4}')
```